# export TODO / DONE with different font face

Tags: org-mode, org-export, fonts

When I export TODO / DONE to pdf, it gets exported as large, bold font. 
I would like to export using regular font. (10 pts). Is it possible ? 
Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `org-latex-format-headline-function` is:

```el
(defun org-latex-format-headline-default-function
    (todo _todo-type priority text tags _info)
  "Default format function for a headline.
See `org-latex-format-headline-function' for details."
  (concat
   (and todo (format "{\\bfseries\\sffamily %s} " todo))
   (and priority (format "\\framebox{\\#%c} " priority))
   text
   (and tags
    (format "\\hfill{}\\textsc{%s}"
        (mapconcat #'org-latex--protect-text tags ":")))))
```

You can define your own `org-latex-format-headline-function` in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).
There you can remove `\\bfseries`. You can also remove `\\sffamily` and do other modifications such like `\fontsize{10pt}{15pt}\selectfont`.

Here I give just the example with the deleted `\\bfseries`:

```el
(defun my-org-latex-format-headline-function
    (todo _todo-type priority text tags _info)
  "My format function for a headline.
See `org-latex-format-headline-function' for details."
  (concat
   (and todo (format "{\\sffamily %s} " todo))
   (and priority (format "\\framebox{\\#%c} " priority))
   text
   (and tags
    (format "\\hfill{}\\textsc{%s}"
        (mapconcat #'org-latex--protect-text tags ":")))))
```

If you modified your init file you should re-evaluate it.
If you don't know otherwise just re-start emacs.
Afterwards you can [customize](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specific-Customization.html#Specific-Customization) the variable `org-latex-format-headline-function` by setting it to `my-org-latex-format-headline-function`.

Comment: Which file I need to edit

Comment: @Vaibhav In your init file. I've modified the answer and added links to the documentation of init files and customization.